# Shopify - no decimal places on price calculations

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to display my prices in laybuy amounts. So a product costing $139 would be 6 payments of $23.17.

My 'price' value is 13900, so I display the following:

```
{{ price | divided_by: 6 | divided_by: 100 }}
```

This displays as 23 instead of 23.17

I've tried adding 2 points for decimal rounding, but this still just displays as 23.

```
{{ price | divided_by: 6 | divided_by: 100 | round: 2 }}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
{{ price | divided_by: 6 | money }}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24511782)

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer.

Comment: @ChavaG Even a short code-only answer is considered an answer, so it isn't very low quality...

Answer (score 1):

You must force the decimal point this way:

`{{ price | divided_by: 6.0 | divided_by: 100 }}`

Just add `.0` after the **divided_by** number.

Comment: Cool, so I've changed it to `{{ price | divided_by: 6.0 | divided_by: 100.0 | round: 2 }}` but now I get `23.5` instead of `23.50`. How to get the zero on end?